# Swift - NSDate - remove part of date

Tags: swift, nsdate

I have a date in following format `2015-02-22T20:58:16+0000`

In order to convert it to NSDate I found following solution

```
var df = NSDateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"
var date = df.dateFromString(myDate)
df.dateFormat = "eee MMM dd yyyy"
var dateStr = df.stringFromDate(date!)
```

But I want to remove +0000 from date. I tried to remove ZZZZm but app crashes.

How can I remove extra +0000 digits ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You ask:

> How can I remove extra +0000 digits?

I'm not sure what you mean, because the resulting `dateStr` *does* have the `+0000` removed.

But let's step back and consider the right way to parse a date string in the format of `2015-02-22T20:58:16+0000`. You should use a `locale` of `en_US_POSIX` as described in [Apple Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1480/_index.html):

```
let myDate = "2015-02-22T20:58:16+0000"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(myDate)
```

When you then want to format that for the end user, reset the `locale` back to `currentLocale`:

```
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "eee MMM dd yyyy"
let dateStr = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!)
```

The `dateStr` then becomes:

> Sun Feb 22 2015

Or, perhaps better, for better localization behavior, use `dateFormatFromTemplate`:

```
let locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
dateFormatter.locale = locale
dateFormatter.dateFormat = NSDateFormatter.dateFormatFromTemplate("eeeMMMdyyyy", options: 0, locale: locale)
let dateStr = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!)
```

In the US, it will appear like above, but in England it will appear as:

> Sun, 22 Feb 2015

Or use one of the standard `dateStyle` values if that works for you. But I'd generally advise against using a hard-coded `dateFormat`, but rather use a format that honors the end-user's localization settings.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't recommend removing time zone when you're parsing results. But if all you want to do is remove the string, you can do it like this:

```
let date = "2015-02-22T20:58:16+0000"
let display = date.substringToIndex(date.characters.indexOf("+")!)
```

This will give you the result of `2015-02-22T20:58:16`