# How to optimally use NSDateFormatter in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'd like to read in a date in this format: 2016-03-15T17:30:00-04:00

and display it like this: Tuesday, March 15, at 5:30 PM

I currently have the following code:

```
var strDate = "2016-03-15T17:30:00-04:00"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
let dateObj = dateFormatter.dateFromString(strDate)

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMMM dd, 'at' h:mm a"
print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateObj!))
```

The code above works but I set the dateFormat of the NSDateFormatter object twice - once to convert a string to an NSDate object and another time to display the date object as a string.

Is this the optimal way to use NSDateFormatter or is there a way I can do it without having to set the dateFormat twice?

An alternative approach would be for me to have two NSDateFormatter objects, each with a different dateFormat. Then I could use each one based on whether I'm reading in the date or displaying it. Would this be a better approach to the problem?

Comment: Note, when parsing that RFC 3339/ISO 8601 date, you don't want to use `curentLocale`, but rather `NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")`. But when displaying for the user, then reset `locale` to `currentLocale`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/35951529/1271826. To the question of one formatter or two, it depends upon whether you'll be doing this repeatedly (in which case, you probably want two separate formatters that you instantiate/configure once that you use repeatedly for each date). If you're doing this for only one date, the difference is not going to be observable.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Rob. I will be parsing and converting multiple date strings so I guess I will create two NSDateFormatters as static variables and give each one its own locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are worried about efficiency, you use two NSDateFormatters, one for each conversion, and set them up only once, probably as static variables. Obviously it's best to measure how much time it actually takes.

Comment: If you do create them once and store them in static variables, be sure the same class is setup to listen for the `NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification` notification. When received, new date formatters should be created.

Comment: Thanks for the response gnasher729, I'll use two NSDateFormatters.
@rmaddy why do I have to listen for the `NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification` notification?

Comment: In case the user changes their locale. Your cached date formatters will be based on the old locale.